# extract svg loading icon from a site

Tags: html, css, svg

I like the success svg animation of http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert, how can I get the code of it? click on the `A success message!` button you will see the nice animated svg there.

Comment: Use the DOM inspector?

Comment: Use the download button, just scroll down, it's a zip file, then inspect the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not use an SVG animation.  It's animating regular DOM elements using CSS.  [Here's a search](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=animateErrorIcon) through the code that shows where the CSS animation is defined.